# Remove '[ from JSON when writing to file in Python

Tags: json, format, to-json

I try to write a JSON to a file to use in another program. I have a dataframe which I make into a JSON like this:

```
jsontest = df_qnapairs.to_json(orient = 'records', force_ascii = False)
```

The output is this

```
Out[9]: '[{"id":1,"answer":"Status på Anleggsoverenskomsten er Oppgjør vedtatt","source":"Automatic","questions":["Hva er status på Anleggsoverenskomsten","Hvordan går det med Anleggsoverenskomsten","Når skjer Anleggsoverenskomsten","Status på Anleggsoverenskomsten","Fortell meg når Anleggsoverenskomsten skjer"],"metadata":[]},{"id":2,"answer":"Status på Kraftlinjefirmaer er Ikke oppgitt","source":"Automatic","questions":["Hva er status på Kraftlinjefirmaer","Hvordan går det med Kraftlinjefirmaer","Når skjer Kraftlinjefirmaer","Status på Kraftlinjefirmaer","Fortell meg når Kraftlinjefirmaer skjer"],"metadata":[]}]'
```

The problem is that the input program runs an error because of the preceding "'[" and trailing "']". How can I remove these when writing to the file?

Comment: Write the JSON-data to a string, remove the brackets and write the rest to the file you want.

Answer (score 0):

if u remove "[" and "]" from it, you change its type from json to dict and in the other program you must be work with dict, i recommend to read and write on file in json format.

if u want to load json in other program you can use :

```
import json    
json_var = json.loads(var)
```

if u force to do it, u can change it to string and remove "[" and "]" :

```
var = str(jsontest)[1:len(str(jsontest))-1]
```